# Cannot execute python script due to maximum recursion depth exceeded error

Tags: python-3.x, windows, error-handling, kivy, executable

I'm watching some tutorial videos on the use of Kivy and I'm trying to convert a python file using a kivy file into an executable. However, even after nearly following the same steps as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEko7jWYKiE&list=PLCC34OHNcOtpz7PJQ7Tv7hqFBP_xDDjqg&index=20), i've been getting this unhandled exception in the script where apparently the maximum recursion depth has exceeded. I've tried searching for multiple ways on how to fix this, such as setting the recursion limit in the spec file, and yet i'm struggling. I'm currently using Python 3.11.4 on Windows 11, if that's any relevant.

[This is the error that shows me whenever I try to run the executable file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XQlg.png)

Just in case, i'll show my main python file as well as the kv file and the spec file to see if i'm missing something there.

For the calc.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (500, 700)

\#Use the Builder module to load a kv file without considering the name of the main class with the kv file
Builder.load_file('calc.kv')

\#This is the ROOT widget
class MyLayout(Widget):
def clear(self):
self.ids.calc_input.text = '0'

    def button_press(self, button):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        if "Error" in prior:
            prior = ''
        if prior == '0':
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{button}'
        else: 
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}{button}'
    
    def math_sign(self, sign):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        last_chara = not prior[len(prior)-1].isnumeric()
        if not last_chara:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior}{sign}'
    
    def dot(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        num_list = prior.split("+")
        #num_list[-1] is the last item of the list
        if "+" in prior and "." not in num_list[-1]:
            prior = f'{prior}.'
            self.ids.calc_input.text = prior
        elif "." in prior:
            pass
        else:
            prior = f'{prior}.'
            self.ids.calc_input.text = prior
    
    def remove(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        prior = prior[:-1] #This means grab the last thing and remove it
        if prior == '':
            prior = '0'
        self.ids.calc_input.text = prior
    
    def pos_neg(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        if "-" in prior:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'{prior.replace("-", "")}'
        else:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = f'-{prior}'
    
    def equals(self):
        prior = self.ids.calc_input.text
        #Error handling
        try:
            #Evaluate the math from the text box
            answer = eval(prior)
            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
        except:
            self.ids.calc_input.text = "Error"
    
        #Addition
        '''
        if "+" in prior:
            num_list = prior.split("+")
            answer = 0.0
            for num in num_list:
                answer += float(num)
            self.ids.calc_input.text = str(answer)
        '''

class CalculatorApp(App):
def build(self):
return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
CalculatorApp().run()
```

For the calc.kv file:

```
<MyLayout>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        TextInput:
            id: calc_input
            text: "0"
            halign: "right"
            font_size: 65
            size_hint: (1, .15)
        
        GridLayout:
            cols: 4
            rows: 5

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "%"

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "C"
                on_press: root.clear()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: u"\u00AB"
                on_press: root.remove()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "/"
                on_press: root.math_sign("/")

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "7"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(7)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "8"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(8)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "9"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(9)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "X"
                on_press: root.math_sign("*")

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "4"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(4)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "5"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(5)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "6"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(6)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "-"
                on_press: root.math_sign("-")

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "1"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(1)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "2"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(2)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "3"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(3)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+"
                on_press: root.math_sign("+")

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "+/-"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.pos_neg()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "0"
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.button_press(0)

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "."
                background_color: (157/255, 157/255, 157/255, 1)
                on_press: root.dot()

            Button:
                size_hint: (.2,.2)
                font_size: 32
                text: "="
                on_press: root.equals()
```

For the spec file:

```
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(
    ['calc.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\UserPC\\kivygui\\calc'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

a.datas += [('Code\calc.kv', 'C:\\Users\\UserPC\\kivygui\\calc\calc.kv', 'DATA')]

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='calc',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    Tree('C:\\Users\\UserPC\\kivygui\\calc\\'),
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='calc',
)
```

Also, whenever I executed the command pyinstaller calc.spec -y, I get a lot of traces and warnings.

[This is what shows whenever I run the command above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGBFP.png)

Help would be very much appreciated.